# Auto-responder rule in Outlook 2010 produces double signature (but only to certain emails)

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I have set up an auto-responder in Outlook 2010 using a custom template, as a staff member will be on vacation for 6 weeks.

It works perfectly, apart from the fact certain people receive two signatures at the bottom of the message instead of one.

When reviewing the "sent" folder, there is no sign of double signatures. In the custom template, there is only 1 copy of the signature. Signatures are set to be applied automatically to new messages or replies- however, if I remove the signature from the template, then it seems *no one* receives a response with the signature.

People sending from Hotmail accounts do *not* receive a duplicate signature.

Gmail users *do* see a duplicate signature.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this inconsistent problem with the inclusion of double signatures in auto-responder emails?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem before. Microsoft told me that it's a bug in Outlook 2010 and that they are working on it. That's now almost 4 months ago. Maybe they are busy with other stuff, I don't know. There are two possible solutions. 1) Upgrade to a newer version of Microsoft Outlook. This works because I did it myself successfully. 2) You could go for a paid auto responder such as the one that you can find at [this page](http://usa.weloveourhost.com/aweber.html). Good luck my friend!

Comment: A known bug in 2010 that they still haven't fixed in 2013? I don't hold out much hope for this getting resolved! Ok, thanks for the info!